# Link in Marquee unclickable!

Tags: html, css, user-interface, marquee

Ok heres my deal, I have a marquee like this:

```
<marquee style=";position:absolute;left:608;top:10;
font-family:Arial;font-size:24pt;
color:#FFFFFF;height:153;
"scrollamount="4" direction="down">
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></marquee>
```

Now for some reason this link is unclickable! It looks like a link but it doesn't act like one. Any way I could make this work guys?

By the way, using FF 3.5

Ok just to show you guys the amount of marquees i'm dealing with go to:

www.letsgettagged.tk, it's not for real but I just needed something to use my idea on.
I'm still going to add more scrollers but this is what I put together really fast.

Comment: There's no such thing as <marquee> in HTML. Don't use non-standard HTML extensions.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I took the above code and it worked fine in FF and IE for me so it must be something else in your code.  Maybe you've got an element overlapping the marquee?

Comment: @marcgg, ok I'm using marquee because I am supposed to make something that doesn't require a super advanced java engine, something that loads fast and is easily manipulated, java is great but for a challenge I thought I would try Marquee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a marquee to make things scroll - use JavaScript. Here's two popular ones:

- [The Silky Smooth Marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)
- [jScroller2 (jQuery plugin)](http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/image-scroller-windiv/)

> [Marquee] is deprecated by the W3C and not advised by them for use in any HTML documents.

Marquee is not officially supported in any browser but IE - any others that do aren't guaranteed to keep doing so, and will probably be dropped at some point since Microsoft is getting over their "let's make totally non-standard stupid tags that break the web" phase.

Comment: Well normally I would, except I'm using a lot of these marquees, like 30. So I don't want a huge amount of java code taking up my page.

Comment: @Tony it's not a "huge amount" of javascript code - it's a few small lines in the top or bottom which hook in to normal HTML and make it scroll at load time.

Comment: @Rex M, ok i'll try it, but the main purpose of this page is to be more css than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Works in Firefox 3.5. Perhaps you should upgrade or tell us which browser you are using or use JavaScript to make things scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens, but I could resolve this issue just stopping the scroll down efect of marquee.

So, to resolve it, do something like:

```
<marquee scrollamount="4" direction="down">
<a href="http://www.google.com" 
   onmouseover="this.parentNode.stop()" 
   onmouseout="this.parentNode.start()">google</a>
</marquee>
```

Comment: @Cleiton, Worked great on a test page! I'm going to try it out on the main page now.

Comment: @Cleiton, Well when I tried it in the main page I was using it looked the same as every other link

Comment: @Tony, i'm sorry, but i dint understand what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Don't use the marquee tag. It's deprecated.

Use alternatives such as [this one](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html) using jquery.